# run a script from rc.local, that exists on an autofs nfs share

Tags: mount, boot, nfs, rc

I mount some nfs exports from a fileserver to my workstation.
The workstation is ubuntustudio 64bit 14.04.

in order to make the mounts as transparent as possible, I have inserted the following in my `.bashrc`

```
SG=sg
mount | grep $SG &> /dev/null 
if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
        sudo mount -o vers=3 fileserver:/nfs/home/nass ~/$SG
fi
```

So I basically mount my folders when the 1st login shell is fired up.
This works fine when I log on to the pc and open up a terminal - which is what I usually do.

I would like this mounting to occur automatically during boot and the obvious choice is to add the above snippet in `/etc/rc.local`.

Then I add a command to run my script, however I want to run it as my user (and not root).

```
/home/nass/audio_setup/scripts/start_audio 2>&1 | tee -a  /tmp/audio.log
```

but as I can see in the `audio.log` file

```
/etc/rc.local: 22: /etc/rc.local: /home/nass/audio_setup/scripts/start_audio: not found
```

why does this happen? what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add the mount command to `/etc/fstab` instead of doing it with a script?  As for the second part, rc.local is run by root by default, so if you aren't taking steps to run as nass you will be mounting the NFS share as /root/sg.  If you want it to run as a different user from rc.local you would have to do something like

`su nass -c '/home/nass/audio_setup/scripts/start_audio'`